# Is learning label embedding by factorizing label co-occurrence matrix unsupervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, matrix-decomposition, word-embeddings

I was working on creating embeddings for medical concepts. These terms/phrases are used for annotating biomedical documents. Now usually the method of creating a co-occurrence matrix and then factorizing it to obtain dense, lower-dimensional vectors is termed as unsupervised learning since annotated data is not involved. I am using the same process but for the annotations themselves. Does this qualify as supervised learning since I need annotated data or does this qualify as unsupervised learning since the method of obtaining the embeddings is unsupervised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use no supervised algorithm (/ do not predict a target variable) you are not using supervised learning.

So it is unsupervised. This is additionally indicated by the fact that you are using an unsupervised method. An unsupervised method can never be used for prediction, because it does not output predefined target variables.

Comment: I was actually a bit confused about this. Thank you so much for the simple explanation!